# How to change timeline.js source to instead of a JSON file receive a JSON string?

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets, timeline.js

I have a timeline using Timeline.js, but currently the story is red from a .json file which to me is not the ideal situation.

I have a servlet that processes information and puts together the JSONObject, that i pass to the page that has the Timeline.js.

Timeline.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Load Example Timeline</title>
<meta name="description" content="TimelineJS example">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="timeline-embed"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeline_config = {
            width:              '100%',
            height:             '600',
            source:             '${timeline}',
            embed_id:           'timeline-embed',               //OPTIONAL USE A DIFFERENT DIV ID FOR EMBED
            start_at_end:       false,                          //OPTIONAL START AT LATEST DATE
            start_at_slide:     '4',                            //OPTIONAL START AT SPECIFIC SLIDE
            start_zoom_adjust:  '3',                            //OPTIONAL TWEAK THE DEFAULT ZOOM LEVEL
            hash_bookmark:      true,                           //OPTIONAL LOCATION BAR HASHES
            font:               'Bevan-PotanoSans',             //OPTIONAL FONT
            debug:              true,                           //OPTIONAL DEBUG TO CONSOLE
            lang:               'pt',                           //OPTIONAL LANGUAGE
            maptype:            'watercolor',                   //OPTIONAL MAP STYLE
            css:                'css/timeline.css',     //OPTIONAL PATH TO CSS
            js:                 'js/timeline-min.js'    //OPTIONAL PATH TO JS
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline/latest/js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The normal thing to have under source would be a json file. But i need to put there a JSONObject that i send from the servlet.

doGet method of the TimelineServlet.java:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<LifeEvent> lifeEvents = new ArrayList<LifeEvent>();

        lifeEvents.add(eventProducer.generateRandomLifeEvent(true));

        JSONObject timeline = JSONString(lifeEvents);

        request.setAttribute("picPath",
                PropertyLoader.getStringValue("PICTURE_DIRECTORY_REL")+"/");
        request.setAttribute("timeline", timeline);

        getServletConfig().getServletContext()
        .getRequestDispatcher("/Timeline.jsp")
        .forward(request, response);
    }
```

I know that the timeline return a well formatted storyline accordingly to the files they provide.

Here is a the generated JSONObject from the code:

```
{
   "Timeline":{
      "headline":"Your life events",
      "startDate": "Tue Feb 18 10:39:10      GMT 2014",
      "text":"Life events with different media types",
      "date":[
         {
            "headline":"Another nice day",
            "startDate": "Tue Feb 18 10:39:10            GMT 2014",
            "text":"Another nice day",
            "asset":[
               {
                  "caption":"Rita HenriquesCarlos Barata",
                  "credit":"Carlos Barata",
                  "media":"porsche.jpg"
               }
            ],
            "endDate": "Tue Feb 18 10:39:10            GMT 2014"
         }
      ],
      "type":"default"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this already.

What i needed to do is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataObject = ${timeline};
        var timeline_config = {
            width:              '100%',
            height:             '600',
            source:             dataObject,
            embed_id:           'timeline-embed',               //OPTIONAL USE A DIFFERENT DIV ID FOR EMBED
            start_at_end:       false,                          //OPTIONAL START AT LATEST DATE
            start_at_slide:     '0',                            //OPTIONAL START AT SPECIFIC SLIDE
            start_zoom_adjust:  '3',                            //OPTIONAL TWEAK THE DEFAULT ZOOM LEVEL
            hash_bookmark:      true,                           //OPTIONAL LOCATION BAR HASHES
            font:               'Bevan-PotanoSans',             //OPTIONAL FONT
            debug:              true,                           //OPTIONAL DEBUG TO CONSOLE
            lang:               'pt',                           //OPTIONAL LANGUAGE
            maptype:            'watercolor',                   //OPTIONAL MAP STYLE
            css:                'css/timeline.css',     //OPTIONAL PATH TO CSS
            js:                 'js/timeline-min.js'    //OPTIONAL PATH TO JS
        }
    </script>
```